# unable to get Cygwin 2.0.2 source code

Tags: cygwin

We are shipping cygwin 2.0.2 with our product and per the licence agreement we need to ship cygwin sources aswell, but not able get the sources for 2.0.2, please help me download....

Answer (score 0):

I got them from the following web site. I had to do it package by package.

### Heading

I got them from the following web site. I had to do it package by package.
http://cygwin.mirror.constant.com/x86/release